# PyQt embed QWebEngineView in Main Window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I'm coming from a tkinter background where everything can be put in a frame.

How can I get my current working codes result (which launches a WebEngine View of a page, google in this instance) to sit inside a main window like shown in the image? Going by the image I want the WebEngine to be housed in the "Green" Box for example.

[image: Pyqt Layout]

Working code including all versions used

```
"""
Python version - 3.7.3
PyQt5            5.15.3
PyQt5-Qt         5.15.2
PyQt5-sip        12.8.1
PyQtWebEngine    5.15.3
PyQtWebEngine-Qt 5.15.2
"""

import sys

from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

url = 'https://google.com'

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# QWebEngineView
browser = QWebEngineView()
browser.load(QUrl(url))
browser.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a QGridLayout:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGridLayout, QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

url = "https://google.com"

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

w = QMainWindow()

browser = QWebEngineView()
browser.load(QUrl(url))

central_widget = QWidget()
w.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

lay = QGridLayout(central_widget)
lay.addWidget(browser, 0, 0, 2, 1)
lay.addWidget(QTextEdit(), 0, 1)
lay.addWidget(QTextEdit(), 1, 1)

lay.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
lay.setColumnStretch(1, 1)

lay.setRowStretch(0, 1)
lay.setRowStretch(1, 1)

w.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a vertical layout to hold the two red boxes. And then use a horizontal layout to hold the QWebEngineView and the vertical layout. Zetcode has a [good tutorial for layouts](https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/layout/). Code heavily borrowed from @eyllanesc:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, 
                             QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout,
                             QTextEdit, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

url = "https://google.com"

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

w = QMainWindow()

browser = QWebEngineView()
browser.load(QUrl(url))

central_widget = QWidget()
w.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

vertical = QVBoxLayout()
vertical.addWidget(QTextEdit())
vertical.addWidget(QTextEdit())

horizontal = QHBoxLayout(central_widget)
horizontal.addWidget(browser)
horizontal.addLayout(vertical)

w.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```